# while updating theme logo got 500 server error on prestashop 1.7.4.2

Tags: prestashop-1.7

> Blockquote
>   i tried to change my store logo in design option through theme and logo option. after updating logo - my front end ends with 500 server error. 
>   Blockquote

Comment: You have to enable "debug mode"

Comment: yes, after debug mode, i got the error in product listing area. Thanks..